# Identifying BigQuery slowness

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the same client implementation, connecting to two different BigQuery warehouses.
The scale is about the same, I need to read and iterate over ~10 millions of records.
With one warehouse it is taking ~20 minutes, with the other warehouse it is taking 5 hours.
Warehouses are in two different accounts but same location. Client is running from the same computer for both warehouses.

What could be the reason for that, any specific config in the BigQuery warehouse I can look into, maybe different plan?

Comment: Are both clients using on demand or is one of them using reserved slots?

Comment: just wanna clarify did you run the same query on both? are both tables the same in terms of partition if any?<br>

Comment: I did run the same query

Comment: do both tables have the same partition or are they both not partitioned?<br>

Comment: @Joevanie they both not partitioned